# Not a duplicate, but still getting Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySQL (ver. 8.0.32)

I have a table whose schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

With the following indexes:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `players_name_unique` (`name`),
ALTER TABLE `players` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `players_name_fulltext` (`name`);
```

There's already the following rows:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | jim |

When I go to run the following query:

```sql
UPDATE `players` SET `name` = '' WHERE id = 2
```

I get the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '??????' for key 'players.players_name_unique'

I'm really stumped, I'm not sure how to remedy this? Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using a different charset?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I dunno, looks like a bug to me: https://dbfiddle.uk/MlcV8HFm

Comment: @mustaccio so I'm not going crazy? its really a bug in MySQL?

Comment: @mustaccio - Over time new `COLLATIONs` are added as Unicode adds/fixes the sorting rules.  So this should be fixed by the user picking a better collation.  If the _latest_ collation fails to compare correctly, then file a MySQL bug.

Answer (score 2):

For  or , you need `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

The antique `_general_ci` collation does not take much into consideration.  Change to `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`.

```
SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;  ==> 1
SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;  ==> 0
```

1 = true (a match)

Comment: A more thorough answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77163335/1766831

Comment: okay, so what would I use since I also need these to not match: `SELECT 'The Divine Comedy' = '  ' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;` - that shows 1 when I need it not to

Comment: @DerekPollard - What is different about your example?